# Как изменить в тип поля из базового класса в дочернем в typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
    export class BaseErrorResponseDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  statusCode: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  error: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  message: string;
}

export class BadRequestDTO extends BaseErrorResponseDTO{

  error: Array<string> | string;

}
```

Comment: Никак. Это несколько противоречит идее TS

Comment: Или сделать BaseErrorResponseDTO  generic

Comment: А как противоречит? Если у тебя ошибка может быть как строкой, так и массивом строк. Если так рассуждать то any  тогда зачем вообще.